# cake php use of table relations

Tags: database, cakephp, model, controller, relationship

Whats the usage of creation relations like

```
 var $belongsTo = array(
        'UserType' => array(
            'className' => 'UserType',
            'foreignKey' => 'user_type_id',
            'conditions' => '',
            'fields' => '',
            'order' => ''
        )
    );
    //The Associations below have been created with all possible keys, those that are not needed can be removed
    var $hasMany = array(
        'UserOpenid' => array(
            'className' => 'UserOpenid',
            'foreignKey' => 'user_id',
            'dependent' => true)
);
```

What if i added a table which created in the sense of "belongsTo", in "hasMany"?
Any error occurs.
How cake uses the relationships specified in the model?

Comment: ok if i specified like this posts hasMany users i cant fetch the user name rite?

Comment: I think you're rather talking about users hasMany posts. Well in that scenario when you select a specific user, you will also get all his comments.

Read about model associations in the Cookbook http://book.cakephp.org/view/78/Associations-Linking-Models-Together

Comment: Can you put your code sample in the code tags? It will make it easier to read.

Comment: this should not have been an answer but a comment. As Paweł said it would be a good idea to read about the relationships at the cakebook, as this is one of the main features of Cake. Also the containable behaviour (http://book.cakephp.org/view/474/Containable) might be interesting for you

Also: If you find an answer useful you might want to reward the person by using the SO-tools

Answer (score 1):

By associating models together you tell CakePHP what to get from the database when you use the find() function. Example:

`posts BelongsTo users` = when you retrieve a post, you will also get data about user to whom this post belongs to (posts.user_id = users.id).

Answer (score 0):

In addition to Paweł's answer:

"belongsTo", "hasMany" etc are simply terms chosen to reflect how the database is designed and how tables are related to each other, which determines how the data will be retrieved.

- `belongsTo` signifies a one-to-many relationship, with the "belonging" model being on the "many" side
- `hasMany` signifies the other side of a one-to-many relationship
- `hasOne` signifies a one-to-one relationship
- `hasAndBelongsToMany` signifies a many-to-many relationship

The specific relationship determines which table holds which foreign key and how to `JOIN` the tables to retrieve data automatically. Look into [Normalization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization) if you have no experience with this.